# Can't include libs for C++ project in VS Code with cmake + vcpkg

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, cmake

I cannot include 3rd party libraries that I install via `vcpkg`.

I am using

- Windows 10
- Visual Studio Code with C/C++, CMake and CMake Tools plugins installed
- VCPKG for getting c++ libraries
- Cygwin g++ compiler
- CMake

```
C:\Users\Jaiel>g++ --version
g++ (GCC) 10.2.0
```

```
C:\Users\Jaiel>vcpkg version
Vcpkg package management program version 2021-05-05-9f849c4c43e50d1b16186ae76681c27b0c1be9d9
```

```
C:\Users\Jaiel>cmake --version
cmake version 3.20.3
```

I was trying to get some test projects done for toying around.

I tried:

- restinio
- wxwidgets
- sqlite3

and all failed.

Following I will give an overview about my attempt for sqlite3:

**Installation**:

```
C:\Users\Jaiel>vcpkg install sqlite3
Computing installation plan...
The following packages will be built and installed:
    sqlite3[core]:x86-windows -> 3.35.4#1
Detecting compiler hash for triplet x86-windows...
A suitable version of powershell-core was not found (required v7.1.0). Downloading portable powershell-core v7.1.0...
Downloading powershell-core...
  https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/releases/download/v7.1.3/PowerShell-7.1.3-win-x86.zip -> C:\vcpkg\downloads\PowerShell-7.1.3-win-x86.zip
Extracting powershell-core...
A suitable version of 7zip was not found (required v18.1.0). Downloading portable 7zip v18.1.0...
Downloading 7zip...
  https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/package/7-Zip.CommandLine/18.1.0 -> C:\vcpkg\downloads\7-zip.commandline.18.1.0.nupkg
Extracting 7zip...
A suitable version of nuget was not found (required v5.5.0). Downloading portable nuget v5.5.0...
Downloading nuget...
  https://dist.nuget.org/win-x86-commandline/v5.5.1/nuget.exe -> C:\vcpkg\downloads\22ea847d-nuget.exe
Using cached binary package: C:\Users\Jaiel\AppData\Local\vcpkg\archives\65\6548fa5df73dbc6b768ef43fa0e5da4ca39334d4.zip
Starting package 1/1: sqlite3:x86-windows
Building package sqlite3[core]:x86-windows...
Building package sqlite3[core]:x86-windows... done
Installing package sqlite3[core]:x86-windows...
Installing package sqlite3[core]:x86-windows... done
Elapsed time for package sqlite3:x86-windows: 27.67 ms

Total elapsed time: 2.061 min

The package sqlite3:x86-windows provides CMake targets:

    find_package(unofficial-sqlite3 CONFIG REQUIRED)
    target_link_libraries(main PRIVATE unofficial::sqlite3::sqlite3)


C:\Users\Jaiel>vcpkg integrate install
Applied user-wide integration for this vcpkg root.

All MSBuild C++ projects can now #include any installed libraries.
Linking will be handled automatically.
Installing new libraries will make them instantly available.

CMake projects should use: "-DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=C:/vcpkg/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake"
```

**tutorial.cxx**

```
#include <sqlite3.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    printf("%s\n", sqlite3_libversion());
    return 0;
}
```

**CMakeLists.txt**

```
# CMakeLists.txt
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0)
project(test)

find_package(unofficial-sqlite3 CONFIG REQUIRED)

add_executable(test tutorial.cxx)

target_link_libraries(test PRIVATE unofficial::sqlite3::sqlite3)
```

**CMake output**

```
[main] Building folder: test 
[main] Configuring folder: test 
[proc] Executing command: "C:\Program Files\CMake\bin\cmake.EXE" --no-warn-unused-cli -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE:STRING=C:/vcpkg/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake -DCMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS:BOOL=TRUE -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER:FILEPATH=C:\cygwin64\bin\x86_64-pc-cygwin-gcc.exe -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER:FILEPATH=C:\cygwin64\bin\x86_64-pc-cygwin-g++.exe -Hc:/Users/Jaiel/Desktop/test -Bc:/Users/Jaiel/Desktop/test/build -G "Unix Makefiles"
[cmake] Not searching for unused variables given on the command line.
[cmake] CMake Error at C:/vcpkg/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake:772 (_find_package):
[cmake]   Could not find a package configuration file provided by
[cmake]   "unofficial-sqlite3" with any of the following names:
[cmake] 
[cmake]     unofficial-sqlite3Config.cmake
[cmake]     unofficial-sqlite3-config.cmake
[cmake] 
[cmake]   Add the installation prefix of "unofficial-sqlite3" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or
[cmake]   set "unofficial-sqlite3_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above
[cmake]   files.  If "unofficial-sqlite3" provides a separate development package or
[cmake]   SDK, be sure it has been installed.
[cmake] Call Stack (most recent call first):
[cmake]   CMakeLists.txt:5 (find_package)
[cmake] 
[cmake] 
[cmake] -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
[cmake] See also "C:/Users/Jaiel/Desktop/test/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
```

It is simply not working with any of the three above. `wxwidgets` gave me a different error that there were some missing LIBS and INCLUDE paths but it didn't work anyways no matter how much I googled.

Can someone help me?

Comment: I guess because vcpkg isn't targetting the same compiler as you are using with cmake?

Comment: how do I check this?

Comment: hey so I noticed in the cmake cache text file that cmake is targetting x64-windows triplet. Where I only had the x86 version installed. Now I installed the sqlite3 again with ``-triplet=x64-windows`` option. Now the above actually works. I think this is what you meant?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One tip is to make sure you call cmake using x64-windows when you installed the x64 vcpkg dependency.

The same idea for x86-windows.